# Cannot plot a histogram from a Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I've used pandas.read_csv to generate a 1000-row dataframe with 32 columns. I'm looking to plot a histogram or bar chart (depending on data type) of each column. For columns of type 'int64', I've tried doing `matplotlib.pyplot.hist(df['column'])` and `df.hist(column='column')`, as well as calling `matplotlib.pyplot.hist` on `df['column'].values` and `df['column'].to_numpy()`. Weirdly, nthey all take areally long time (>30s) and when I've allowed them to complet, I get unit-height bars in multiple colors, as if there's some sort of implicit grouping and they're all being separated into different groups. Any ideas about what I can do to get a normal histogram? Unfortunately I closed the charts so I can't show you an example right now.

Edit - this seems to be a much bigger problem with Int columns, and casting them to float fixes the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the columns are fully numeric?  Did you look at `df.info()`?

Answer (score -1):

Follow these two steps:

- import the Histogram class from the Matplotlib library
- use the "*plot*" method, which will accept a dataframe as argument

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.hist(df['column'], color='blue', edgecolor='black', bins=int(45/1))
```

Here's the [source](https://vitalflux.com/histogram-plots-using-matplotlib-pandas-python/).